# Sort array having object of class

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting

Hi I have an array having 100 element. and each element is of type class `Data` with the following members:

- name
- price
- stock
- description

How can I sort the array on based on the `price` member of class `Data`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the NSArray class documentation? There are a bunch of methods for sorting elements. Have you looked the 'Collections Programming Topics' guide, which has descriptions and examples?

Comment: Yes, please read the NSArray documentation.  Your answer is there, should you bother to read it.

Comment: This SO question seems pretty similiar.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *priceDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES] autorelease]; // ascending YES or NO depends on your requirement
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: priceDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

also see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you have  method for price the object within array class you can use `NSComparisonResult`:

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareprice : (id) element
{
    return [price compare: [element price ]];
}
```